# Are any Certificate Authorities using 4096 bit keys for their intermediate and root certificates?

Tags: rsa, public-key, key-size, certificates

Are any Certificate Authorities using 4096 bit keys for their intermediate and root certificates?

I know you can, of course, use a 4096 bit key for your server certificate, but I usually see 2048 bit keys from the Certification Authorities, and wonder if any are using 4096 bit keys yet?

Thank you.

Comment: This is probably better suited on [itsecurity](http://security.stackexchange.com/), I don't see any question in here related to cryptography. This might sound strange to you, but to explain it with an analogy - a question about which companies sell chocolate cakes is off-topic on a baking forum.

Comment: You might be right. I thought about that shortly after posting, but still thought that users here might have a good knowledge of this.